# Is it possible to find the dimensions of a rectangle from the inner radius and the diagonal?

Tags: geometry, rectangles

It seems that given the variables length, width, area, perimeter, diagonal length, outer radius,inner radius of a rectangle, it is (almost)possible to get every other variable if any pair of said variables is given. The only pair that I can't figure out yet is the data pair inner radius and diagonal.

Is it also possible to get the length and width (and therefore everything else) given the inner radius r and the diagonal length d?

Comment: Ok, how is there an inner radius of a rectangle which cannot in general be circumscribed about a circle?

Answer (score 0):

The width of the rectangle will just be $2$ times the inner radius and then you can use Pythagoras to get the length using the diagonal.